# schedule task to run perl script from command line

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I hope I can explain my problem clearly.

I have a Perl script that I run from the command line like this

```
perl update_blastdb.pl databaseName --passive
```

As you see, I must add parameters in the command line.

I want to automate the running of this script weekly with an parameter.

The task manager in Windows can schedule a task to run automatically, but I think if I give the Perl file path to the task scheduler, it will be run without any parameters.

What is the best way to do what I want? I thought of creating a new Perl file that has:

- Arguments in variables fields
- A command variable that sends the parameter with `update_blastdb.pl` to the command prompt.

But I am just thinking and I don't know whether this is possible.

Can anyone help me find the right direction please?

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know how to pass the parameters to your script or how to run it at all? Parameter passing is explained [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0e12e4bc-b8f2-45b9-97be-e768f3bca2dd/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-windows-scheduled-task?forum=winservergen), for example.

Comment: @Perl Dog my problem is both how to pass parameters and how to run it. As I said, I am new to all these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought it was as simple as this

```
at 05:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F cmd /c perl update_blastdb.pl databaseName --passive
```

The only problem might be that the current directory isn't what you expect. Scheduled tasks run under the *System* account with their current directory set to *SYSTEMROOT*, which is generally `C:\Windows`

Comment: do you mean to write a perl script that contains just this line? and schedule task to run it?

Comment: How about :at 05:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F cmd /cd C:\Program Files\NCBI\blast-2.3.0+\bin, cmd perl update_blastdb.pl databaseName --passive?